# The table "{{post}}" for active record class "Post" cannot be found in the database.

Tags: yii

if i give 
localhost/yii/framework/blogs/index.php/

it will shows 
The system is unable to find the requested action "index".

if i click home the link goes to 
localhost/yii/framework/blogs/index.php/post/index

and shows the error

The table "{{post}}" for active record class "Post" cannot be found in the database.

Comment: can anyone help me what to do?

Comment: Do you have a table named 'post' in the database?

Comment: Please go through and read the documentation first. The last response just shows you are copying code and expecting it to work without understanding how/why.

Comment: no i just created yii application..it will not showing the index page if i connect db...

Comment: If you read the documentation on the blog example, it will show that the sample uses a sqlite database. You need to change your connection string, OR duplicate the table structure from the SQLite file in your MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

This error shows there is no table post in the database connected .

if the table exist , then check the table prefix configured main.php . There is no prefix used in the database , remove the tablPrefix in main.php

```
'db'=>array(
  'connectionString' => 'xxxxx',
  'username' => 'xxxxx',
  'password' => 'xxxxx',
  'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
),
```

Comment: i have used 'db'=>array(
   'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
   'emulatePrepare' => true,
   'username' => 'root',
   'password' => 'password',
   'charset' => 'utf8',
   'tablePrefix' => '',
  ),

Comment: i have 2 tables named employee and department in the test database.

Comment: I think you dont need post model , go to model delete the Post.php (models/Post.php)

Comment: deleted it will shows ---PHP warning

include(Post.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: ok. check your controller, remove the unnecessary controllers. Also check your necessary controller , Post class is used , if so comment that line.

Comment: deleted the folder it will shows Unable to resolve the request "post".

Comment: i said only controller files not folders. what (controller / action you   are try to access ) . i am asking your Url .

Comment: now it will showing like that The system is unable to find the requested action "index".

Comment: ok better do one thing , restore all  the deleted files. create a dummy post table , you can take the table column from Post.php. Try this and let me know

Comment: 'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:w+>/<id:d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:w+>/<action:w+>/<id:d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:w+>/<action:w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),

Comment: This seems correct only . Please follow as i said before .

Comment: create post table with the following columns " id, title, content, status,tags" : for more details see the Post.php -> function rules()

Comment: created table and run it will shows ----CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'update_time' in 'order clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`title` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`content` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`status` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`tags` AS `t0_c4` FROM `post` `t` WHERE (status=2) ORDER BY update_time DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: add update_time  (datetime) in the post table ,and run .if any error throws similarly for create_time do the same

Comment: now also same error --CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'update_time' in 'order clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`title` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`content` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`status` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`tags` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.` update_time` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`create_time` AS `t0_c6` FROM `post` `t` WHERE (status=2) ORDER BY update_time DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: create two columns in the post table update_time, create_time , both are datetime

Comment: created...and it has the 2 columns now..but same error

Comment: add this line   array('create_time,update_time','safe')  in Post.php , in the  function rules

Comment: where i have to add which place